# python django Localization

Tags: python, django

I'm using django Internationalization current now.
When i use in template such as

```
{% trans "i love you" %}
```

it works fine.

But when i define it in python file

```
_("i love you")
```

it still outputs the English word.

If I replace `_("i love you")` with `"我爱你"`, it says:

```
   SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe4'
```

Comment: Regarding your "SyntaxError" you need to be sure to set the encoding of our source file properly, see this link for details: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html#source-code-encoding

Comment: Do you use `(u)gettext` or `(u)gettext_lazy` for `_`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't replace `_("i love you")` in your views.py but in the .po file generated by `django-admin.py compilemessages` ([see here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/i18n/)).

hope it helps

Comment: #: forum_modules/default_badges/badges.py:267
#, fuzzy
msgid "i love you"
msgstr "我爱你"

see , it 's  `#, fuzzy` forbidden the translation.delete `#, fuzzy` and it works .